# Run OpenCV scripts as a part of a Python program

Tags: python, opencv

As part of a Python program, I wish to run [this script](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/tf_text_graph_ssd.py) from the OpenCV repository that creates a .pbtxt TensorFlow frozen graph.

Can this be done by importing the relevant file from the cv package?

Comment: There are python bindings for openCV

Comment: I saw that the question was too general. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to import the classes in that file through the OpenCV python package if that is what your asking.

To make the code "importable" you can move the .py file into your own project and then make an empty file named `__init__.py` in the same directory. Alternatively you could wrap this code up into its own package, install it and then import it.

[See here for learning more about how this works.](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html)